# select inner join giving not correct result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table, need to call select twice, with two different where condition, and put it back as one.

If I run select`s separately, it give me correct result, but select in one query with inner join does not, second select is doubled.

The table looks like:

```
amount | paydate    | ...
-337   | 2018-01-10 | ...
1467   | 2018-01-10 | ...
-322   | 2018-02-10 | ...
1452   | 2018-02-10 | ...
```

The result should be as:

```
January  | 1467 | -337
February | 1452 | -322
```

However I get

```
January  | 1467 | -322
February | 1452 | -322
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
    Q1.month, 
    Q1.ttlincome, 
    Q1.paydate,
    Q2.ttldebid
FROM (
        SELECT MONTHNAME(`paydate`) as month, 
        (`amount`) AS ttlincome, 
        paydate, propertiseid
                FROM `test`
            WHERE `test`.`amount` > 0 
              AND `test`.`paydate` BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31' 
            GROUP BY YEAR(`test`.`paydate`), MONTH(`test`.`paydate`)
    ) AS Q1
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT (`amount`) AS ttldebid,
        FROM `test`
            WHERE `test`.`amount` < 0 
              AND `test`.`paydate` BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
            GROUP BY YEAR(`test`.`paydate`), MONTH(`test`.`paydate`)
    ) AS Q2
GROUP BY YEAR(Q1.`paydate`), MONTH(Q1.`paydate`)
```

Maybe there is a better way to get this working?

Comment: You need a join condition

Comment: You have no `ON` clause to specify how the rows of the two subqueries relate to each other.

Comment: You're using `GROUP BY` but you have no aggregation functions. That makes very little sense.

Comment: I removed it for this board, there is another field, but query is working exactly this same with or without ON clause.

Comment: It works when I add the `ON` clause: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30da94/3

Comment: You are the man! Did not add parameter to second select... so my ON clause was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: We need to see the primary key

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your query should be like this

```
SELECT 
    Q1.month, 
    Q1.ttlincome, 
    Q1.paydate,
    Q2.ttldebid
FROM (
        SELECT distinct MONTHNAME(`paydate`) as month, 
        (`amount`) AS ttlincome, 
        paydate, propertiseid
                FROM `test`
            WHERE `test`.`amount` > 0 
              AND `test`.`paydate` BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31' 

    ) AS Q1
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT distinct (`amount`) AS ttldebid,MONTHNAME(`paydate`) as month
        FROM `test`
            WHERE `test`.`amount` < 0 
              AND `test`.`paydate` BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'

    ) AS Q2
on Q1.month=Q2.month
```

Comment: There's no `paydate` in `Q2`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do:

```
select monthname(paydate),
       max(amount), min(amount)
from t
where paydate >= '2018-01-01' and paydate < '2019-01-01'
group by monthname(paydate)
order by min(paydate);
```

Or, if you can have more than 2 rows:

```
select monthname(paydate),
       sum(case when amount > 0 then amount end),
       sum(case when amount < 0 then amount end)
from t
where paydate >= '2018-01-01' and paydate < '2019-01-01'
group by monthname(paydate)
order by min(paydate);
```